# Ubuntu 17.04 ugly boot up

Tags: boot

I have an Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) running on a HP EliteBook 8460p.

Ubuntu is installed on a new Samsung 850 EVO SSD and I don't have any kind of dual boot or traces of Windows. When I power up my laptop the Ubuntu boot is very *glitchy* and ugly.

First I see a normal HP logo and that's fine, then theres a black screen for one second, one second of purple color, then again my HP logo and then a purple screen with UBUNTU logo with some dots, then a blinking underline in upper left corner and something like `sda1/clean, ... blocks...` something like that. And it shows another black screen and finally my login screen.

I would love to make this cleaner, like the Ubuntu logo appearing right after the HP logo until the greeter comes up

Can anyone help with this?